# How to Query Foreign Key as Filter( as WHERE clause) using LINQ and ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am currently finding hard to display a list of fishes in my project. I have two entities, Fish and User which has one to many relation. With the user(UserID) being the foreign key, filtering the fish based on who posted the fish is what I am trying to achieve for this project.

Here is both my entities :

```cs
public class Fish
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(100)]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float WeightKg { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int Stock { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public float Price { get; set; }
    public string Image { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public FishCategory Category { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public User Seller { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(25)]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

This is my repository with the current logic I am try to implement :

```cs
public IEnumerable<Fish> GetFishByUserId(int userId)
{
    return _databaseContext.Fishes
        .Where(fish => fish.Seller.ID == userId).ToList();
}
```

I ended up getting an empty array without the data. I do have a list of fishes data in the database.

[image]

This is the User database which has user data.

[image]

Any solution will do, thanks.

Comment: Better show generated SQL. It will answer a lot of questions.

Comment: Are there any fluent configuration/data annotations missing in the posted code? Where is the `User Seller` and `int UserID` association? Since they are not following EF Core naming conventions, `UserID` is not automatically associated as FK representing the `Seller` navigation property.

Comment: @IvanStoev: I was thinking the same as you, but after testing the case, it turns out that EF Core is clever enough to handle that case as long as there is a single property of type `User`. BR

Comment: Can we see the code that calls `GetFishByUserId` and some kind of proof that `GetFishByUserId` is called with userId = 1?   BR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the culprit thanks to @Roar S for asking me which API method is calling the "GetFishByUserId()". Also thanks to @mustafa hassan for fully defining the one-to-many relationship.

The issue was on the API method. Take a look at this code:

```html
[HttpGet("seller/{userId}", Name = "GetFishByUserId")]
public ActionResult <IEnumerable<FishReadDTO>> GetFishByUserId(int userId)
{
    var fishes = _repository.GetFishByUserId(userId);
    if(fishes == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<FishReadDTO>>(fishes));
}
```

Here in the API url which is "seller/{userId}" the parameter name must match with the method's parameter name which is also "userId". Mine was a different name hence the value wasn't being passed to the method's parameter and eventually to the repository.